# Audio, video tags in HTML 5 is not working in my WPF application through cefsharpchromium browser

Tags: wpf, html, html5-video, html5-audio, cefsharp

Am using cefsharp chromium browser to load a web page within my WPF application.

While running the web application directly in the browser , Am able to view video and audio is also working. But While am trying to load the web page in my WPF application using Cefsharp Chromium browser , Video and audio is not playing.

Am using cefsharp.WPF v53.1

Comment: `Due to licensing issues default builds do not support proprietary codecs like H264 and MP3, sites like Netflix won't play video/audio.` - copied directly from the release notes. Look in the `Debug.log` file, should be in your executing folder.See if your getting errors.

Comment: Try http://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files/ and play the demo video at the bottom. Validate that your browser is working correctly.